# DataTables.net Scroller and Fixed Columns extension used together

Tags: datatables, scroller

I'm making some experiment with DataTables.net jQuery plugin.

Did anybody use scroller extension together with fixed columns one?
When I try to apply both extensions, only the header has fixed columns, while the body doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

I want a simple table with 40 columns (10 fixed) and 20000 rows.
Here is my code (it uses just test data, table contents are not important at the moment):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 20000 ; i++) {
            data.push([i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, i + 4, i + 5, i + 6, i + 7, i + 8, i + 9, i + 10, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i]);
        }
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
            data: data,
            deferRender: true,
            dom: "frtiS",
            scrollY: 1000,
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true
        });
        new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(oTable, {
            leftColumns: 10
        });
    });
```